# Loop works fine on a single sheet, having trouble looping through workbook.

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have a workbook with several sheets and I am trying to detect numbers in C9:C200 and copy them in a cell three columns over - for every sheet starting at the 7th. The code within the outermost forloop works fine on a single sheet but I get an error message when I try to loop it through the rest of the sheets. I think I have two problems:

1. I'm not sure how to bounce the c9:c200 range from sheet to sheet as it loops through the workbook
2. I think I need to tell VBA to reset the evaluations so that it starts from scratch on the next sheet.

Am I going in the right direction with this?

Thanks!

Sub MoveQtrLoop()

```
Dim CEL As Range
Dim RNG As Range
Dim I As Integer
Dim WrkSht As Worksheet
Dim WS_Count As Integer

I = 0

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For Each WrkSht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    I = I + 1

        If 6 < I < WS_Count Then

            Set RNG = ActiveSheet.Range("c9:C200")

                For Each CEL In RNG
                         If CEL.HasFormula = True Then
                            CEL.Offset(, 3) = CEL.Value

                         ElseIf IsNumeric(CEL) = True Then
                                    CEL.Offset(, 3) = CEL.Value

                         Else

                         End If ****ERR. OCCURS HERE****
                Next CEL
        Else

        End If
    Next WrkSht
```

End Sub

Comment: what does the error say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare your range you are doing it based on ActiveSheet but you are not activating the following sheets through each loop. But rather than using ActiveSheet just set the target range with your WrkSht variable:

```
Set RNG = WrkSht.Range("c9:C200")
```

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Thank you both, The debugger still runs to the innermost end if. Looks like I've still got some work to do.

Comment: What error are you getting though? Remove that `ELSE` command cause it's not doing anything.

Comment: Code Execution Has Been Interrupted. When I step through I get [Cel.Value = 40011.15] , the 40011.15 being an actual number in the data somewhere.

Comment: restarted the worksheet and ran the same code and it executed cleanly, not sure why... in any case, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It's not looping because you're using `ActiveSheet`'s range.  Change it to:

```
Dim CEL As Range
Dim RNG As Range
Dim I As Integer
Dim WrkSht As Worksheet
Dim WS_Count As Integer

I = 0
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For Each WrkSht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    I = I + 1
        If 6 < I < WS_Count Then
            Set RNG = wrksht.Range("c9:C200")
                For Each CEL In RNG
                         If CEL.HasFormula = True Then
                            CEL.Offset(, 3) = CEL.Value
                         ElseIf IsNumeric(CEL) = True Then
                                    CEL.Offset(, 3) = CEL.Value
                         Else

                         End If
                Next CEL
        Else

        End If
    Next WrkSht
End Sub
```

Comment: Beat me by  15 seconds ;)